# Buttons are not working. Entering Data through TextFields

Tags: java, database, swing

I want to enter data through textfields and save them. But buttons are not working. There are no errors while I'm compiling and not even in database connection. I guess there is a logical error.

```
public class Database {
    private static JPanel panel;
    private static JLabel sname;
    private static JLabel saddress;
    private static JTextField t;
    private static JTextField t1;

    private static JButton Delete = new JButton("Delete");
    private static JButton update = new JButton("Update");
    private static JButton save = new JButton("Save");
    private static Container c;
    private static Connection con;
    private static Statement st;
    private static ResultSet rs;

    Database() {

        connect();

    }

    public void connect(){

            try{
                System.out.println("Entered");
                System.out.println("Database connection started...");
                con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://D:\\test.mdb");
                System.out.println("Hello satarted");
                st = con.createStatement();
                System.out.println("Connection ok.");
                while(rs.next())
                {
                    System.out.println(rs.getString("Student Name"));

                    System.out.println(rs.getString("Student Address"));
                    System.out.println();

                }

                catch (SQLException e){
                    System.err.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Database gui = new Database();

        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setTitle("School Management System");
        f.setSize(300, 200);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        sname = new JLabel("Student Name");
        t = new JTextField(10);
        saddress = new JLabel("Student Address");
        t1 = new JTextField(10);

        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(sname);
        panel.add(t);
        panel.add(saddress);
        panel.add(t1);
        // panel.add(insert);
        panel.add(Delete);
        panel.add(update);
        panel.add(save);
        f.add(panel);

        try {
            rs.next();
            t.setText(rs.getString("Student Name"));
            t1.setText(rs.getString("Student Address"));

        } catch (Exception ex) {

        }

    }

    public void btnAction() {
        save.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                String name = t.getText();
                String address = t1.getText();
                try {
                    rs.moveToInsertRow();
                    rs.updateString("Student Name", name);
                    rs.updateString("Student Address", address);
                    rs.insertRow();

                    rs.close();
                } catch (Exception ex) {

                }
            }

        });
        update.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                String sname = t.getText();
                String saddress = t1.getText();
                try {
                    rs.updateString("Student name", sname);
                    rs.updateString("Student address", saddress);
                    rs.updateRow();

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Record Updated!");

                } catch (Exception e) {

                }
            }

        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Mind the formatting please.

Comment: Your `catch` statements in the button action listeners are empty. This means if there are errors, you won't see them. Add at least `e.printStackTrace()` to the catch. In any case, you never cass `btnAction()` anywhere, so your action listeners aren't registered. And you are using everything as `static` which you shouldn't.

Comment: Note that `e.printStckTrace();` as suggested by @RealSkeptic is both shorter and more informative than `System.err.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());`

Comment: I added the (System.err.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());) i the catch block .. but when i removed static from each of these variables. I got so many errors in the main method which says-                                     non-static variable sname cannot be referenced from a static context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when i removed static from each of these variables. I got so many errors

Yes, any time you see a class full of static variables you know the class is designed incorrectly.

Start with the working example from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Text Field](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html). Download the `TextDemo` code and understand how it works and then make the changes for your logic.

Note how the class extends a JPanel where all the variables and components are defined and there is no need for any static variable. Your code should look something like this.

Once you have a better designed class you can then start to debug your code to figure out why the SQL isn't working.

Comment: There were logics mistake and now I Changed the code. Its working